# Parameter handling from ASP.NET Backend to Angular

Tags: asp.net, angular, file

I don't know how to include a function parameter that is defined in my backend, in my frontend endpoint. This is my backend function declaration :

```
public IActionResult Post([FromForm]Employee emp, IFormFile file)
        {
            ...            }
```

And I've tried including the IFormFile file in my frontend doing this in my angular service :

```
createEmployee(employee:FormData, file:File):Observable<ArrayBuffer>{
    return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(`${this.apiURLEmployee}`, employee, file)
  }
```

But I am getting the error : No overload matches this call.

The error appears on the file that is in the http.post .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you are providing `file` for the options parameter in the `post` method.

This is the `HttpClient.Post` definition:

```
post(url: string, body: any|null, options: {
    headers?: HttpHeaders|{[header: string]: string | string[]},
    context?: HttpContext,
    observe?: 'body'|'events'|'response',
    params?: HttpParams|
          {[param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string|number|boolean>},
    reportProgress?: boolean,
    responseType?: 'arraybuffer'|'blob'|'json'|'text',
    withCredentials?: boolean,
  } = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.request<any>('POST', url, addBody(options, body));
  }
```

You need to put employee and form into the same object (`{employee, file}`) and post it like this:

```
createEmployee(employee:FormData, file:File):Observable<ArrayBuffer>{
    return this.http.post<ArrayBuffer>(`${this.apiURLEmployee}`, {employee, file})
}
```

This will get rid of your error in Angular.

I also suspect that your .NET endpoint is incorrect (but test it first). I think you might need to combine the 2 arguments into a new class like this:

```
// ExampleInput.cs
public class ExampleInput{
    public Employee Emp {get;set;}
    public IFormFile File {get;set;}
}

...
// SomeController.cs
public IActionResult Post(ExampleInput input) {...}
```

Comment: @Lalilulelo If this resolved your issue, then please mark this as the correct answer so that this question no longer appears as unresolved. Judging by your most recent question I am assuming that it did?